# Operator "+" cannot be aplied to android.text.SpannableString

Tags: android, spannablestring

`enter code here`I am creating a small Android app. I would like to display a text in a textview with multiple parts to click on. I am using android.text.SpannableString to this purpose. Here is my code:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);



        final Spannable sd = new SpannableString("Android Multiple clickable strings in textview");
        final ClickableSpan clickableSpan3 = new ClickableSpan() {


            @Override
            public void onClick(View textView) {
                Toast toast1 = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "first", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                toast1.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
                toast1.show();
            }
        };
        final ClickableSpan clickableSpan4 = new ClickableSpan() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View textView) {

                Toast toast2 = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "second", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                toast2.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
                toast2.show();
            }

        };
        sd.setSpan(clickableSpan3, 8, 16, SPAN_POINT_POINT);
        sd.setSpan(clickableSpan4, 17, 26,Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);

        TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.hello);
        textView.setText(sd);
        textView.setMovementMethod(new LinkMovementMethod());


    }
```

It works normally, but if I change code for adding new words to TextView

mTextView.setText(sd**+"my words"**);
mTextView.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());

all spanned selections disappears. How to avoid it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [TextUtils.concat(CharSequence... text)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextUtils.html#concat(java.lang.CharSequence...)) method.
From the docs:

> Returns a CharSequence concatenating the specified CharSequences,
>   retaining their spans if any.

The code would go like this:

```
mTextView.setText(TextUtils.concat(sd,"my words"));
```